# Sync, share and backup policy using NAS

Tags: macos, backup, network-shares

Trying to come up with a way to keep in sync while sharing and keeping a backup of my music/photos and movies.

Currently I have an iMac in Greece and a MBP with me in the UK. As a result I've ended up with 2 iPhoto and iTunes libraries not to mention Documents scattered here and there, user settings etc.

I also like to have a backup in case of a drive failure or the need to clean install.

It seems that iPhoto and iTunes don't work really well with networked libraries.

The way I think about it is to have a NAS where I keep my iTunes and iPhoto library but also rsync daily to my MBP to have a local copy. That way my files are shared across the network as well as act like a backup. In addition I get to have my files wherever I take my MBP but also have the ability to clean install.

The tricky part comes from keeping in sync the iMac which is miles away. Again I'm considering a mirror setup (NAS, rsync to the iMac) as well as an rsync between the two NAS.

It pretty much resembles the way Dropbox works, sans the requirement to go through their servers but I'm no "superuser" and don't really know if it is even feasible to have such a setup. Looks like there are so many things that can go wrong.